# Paging with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, pagination

Okay, right now I've got this statement and it's working well (note I've already sorted the list before executing this statement so `Reverse` is simply allowing me to pop off the last page):

```
return results.Take(pageSize * pageIndex).Reverse().Take(pageSize);
```

But there's got to be a more efficient way ... can anybody show me the way?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually Skip() and Take() methods are using for paging in linq.

Comment: (off topic-ish): also look at the PagedList nuget package , http://nuget.org/packages/PagedList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Skip operator.

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns
>   the remaining elements.
>    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx

For example:

```
return results.Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use **Skip**

```
return results.Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize);
```